# How to go to a line when clicked on a Visual Studio scrollbar caret

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio, is it possible to navigate to exact position (code line) in the editor - while expanding regions - when clicked on a visual studio scrollbar caret? (like how Resharper does)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried enabling map mode for the scroll bar?

Comment: @Lennart, yes, i have but that doesn't particularly help to navigate to 'the' line just by clicking on the scrollbar

Comment: VS 2022 and still this is a problem

Comment: It's a shame C# support isn't better in VSCode, b/c it does what you're looking for. It looks like newer versions (i.e. .NET Core, which include [portable PDBs](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Portable-PDBs)) of C# are becoming [more amenable to it](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp) though.

Answer (score 1):

For later user who use VS 2022

Enable map mode:
Option > Text Editor > All Languages > Scroll Bars

Choose Use map mode for vertical scroll bar. Show overview: set to Off

Comment: Thanks!!!! I've been looking for this feature for months.  On my VS 2022 the menu path is Tools > Option > ...